# how do i write to an html from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem with my javascript and html

i was trying to write a html element using a function from my javascript
here's my code

```
function write();
{
 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
  document.write("<td>"+arr[i]+"</td><br>")
 }
}
```

and code at my index.html, i want put that write inside my table row

```
<tr>
<script>write();</script>
</tr>
```

i have attached my javscript to my html document, but nothing happened
can u guys help me to put make that function work??
thanks guys!!

Comment: You should close the row with `</tr>` instead of `<tr>`

Comment: This is not the proper way. you have to give specific id and write data using getElementById and innerHTML.

Comment: as Bhavesh has mentioned you need to get the element you want to add this HTML to. do this using `document.getElementById("myElement")` obviously replacing myElement for the id of your actual HTML element. You can add content in various ways but try researching `.appendChild()` and `.innerHTML` this should help.

Comment: Or you could use jQuery.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where does arr variable come from? This question is not clear at all. Anyway, don't put "<script>" or "<br>" tags inside a table row.

Answer (score 3):

As per your question description, for writing html or dom elements say, you need to first create element(until you already have in which case you can use `document.getElementById()`) and then add text.

For creating:

```
# Create new dom element
var td = document.createElement("td");
```

Adding text:

```
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hiii'))
```

**In your case:**

```
function write(){
  var element;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    element = document.createElement("td");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your row an id like this:

```
<tr id="myRow">

</tr>
```

Also i would recommend you to implement the function call in your javascript file.
Try something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    write();
};

function write(){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("myRow").innerHTML += "<td>" + arr[i] + "</td><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check html below:

```
<table>
   <tr id="myid" >

   </tr>
</table>
```

and javascript would be like this

```
var row = document.getElementById("myid");
var x = row.insertCell(0);
x.innerHTML="New cell";
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr id='row'></tr>    
</table>
```

JS:

```
function write(arr) {
    var row = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        row += '<td>'+arr[i]+'</td>'
    }

    document.getElementById('row').innerHTML = row;
}

write(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uhaEL/